# Handling 302 status code in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

In my app, I have an authentication mechanism that uses 302 to redirect the user to a login view.

The client side is in angularjs. It uses $routeProvider to map urls to views. Now, when I click on a link (that is bound to a view in the route provider) and the user is not authenticated, I would like to redirect to the login screen.

But instead of this, the content of the login screen is embedded in the calling page. Is there a way to just redirect when 302 status code is received?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to this behaviour?